# Why doesnt dash work on a server but works on jupyter?

Tags: python, json, server, dashboard, plotly-dash

I wrote a Dash program using python and it works on Jupyter notebook. But It doesn't work on server. I send my geometric data on server by:
scp data.json username@10.0.0.0:/directory

Why in server I cant run this python code:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import json
import dash
import swifter
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df= gpd.read_file('data.json').to_crs("EPSG:4326")

upper_bound = df.swifter.apply(lambda row: norm.cdf(5,loc= row['p_mean'],scale=row['p_std']),axis=1)

app = dash.Dash()
server = app.server

app.layout = html.Div([
        dcc.RangeSlider(
            id='range-slider',
            className='range-slider' ,
            min=0, max=3,
            step=None,
            marks={
                0: {'label': df.name.iloc[0]},
                1: {'label':df.name.iloc[1]},
                2: {'label':df.name.iloc[2]},
                3: {'label':df.name.iloc[3]}
                },
            value=[0, 1] ) 
])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: what is the error? are you sure the path is correct?

Comment: There is no error. but in doesn't work. Both app.py and data.json are in the same folder.

Comment: please include a data.json file which I can use to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I want to speed up calculating "norm" , I was used "swifter". It works on PC but it doesn't work on server! After removing that, It works!